# How to deselect prime numbers who end with 7 in range 1-100 in Python?

Tags: python, primes

```
list = []

for i in range(2,100):
    primeflag=True
    for num in list:
        if(i%num==0):
            primeflag=False

    if(primeflag):
        print str(i)
        list.append(i)
print list
```

What should I put to remove prime numbers which end with 7?

Comment: A tip: you can get rid of the need for "primeflag" using the `for... else` idiom with `break`.

Comment: Another tip: it's not a good idea to call your list `list` as it conflicts with the built in type of that name.

Answer (score 1):

Mod your number by 10 and check if it equals 7 prior to appending it to the final list.

```
if(i % 10 != 7):
    print str(i)
    list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of achieving what you want to do, and you'll need to see what fits your particular problem.

One way of approaching this:

- Define a method isprime(n) - You can figure out or look up the implementation somewhere, I'm sure

Then:

```
yourlist = [x for x in xrange(2, 100) if isprime(x) and x % 10 != 7]
```

This is a good first approach, there are, of course, more complex possibilities, like using generators, a modified Erasthothenes Sieve, etc, but you can explore those options after you get one working.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can convert any numeric value to string representation using `str` function.

So, you can do: -

```
num  = 17
str_num = str(num)
```

Then, to test for the last digit not equal to 7, you can access the last character of the string, and compare it with `'7'`. To access the last character, use `str_num[-1]`.

So, the condition you need is: -

```
if str_num[-1] != '7':
    # don't add it to list
```

---

Also, your inner loop seems to be incorrect. You are checking the modulus of `i`, by dividing it against every number in `list`, rather, you should check for modulus till `i ** 0.5`. Also, you can make use of `else` part of your `for` loop, to avoid using a `boolean flag`. So, your modified code should look like

```
for i in range(2,100):
    for num in range(2, int(i ** 0.5) + 1):
        if(i % num == 0):
            break

    else:
        if str(i)[-1] != '7':
            my_list.append(i)
```

And `else` of `for` is executed, when the `for` loop completes execution without any break.

---

Although not directly related to the actual question, but you can consider checking out [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm, to generate prime numbers in a given range.

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.

Comment: @popkica639.. Ah! Sorry. Forgot to convert back to int. Updated code. You can try now.

Comment: Tnx you, you saved my day :)

Comment: Sorry its me again now I have a NameError: name 'my_list' is not defined , I really new in Python :(

Comment: @popkica639.. Change your `list` declaration to `my_list`. `list` is a built in. You should not use it as the name of your variable.